# ARCH coefficient in GARCH models

Tags: time-series, clustering, regression-coefficients, garch, volatility-forecasting

Is anyone knows to interpret  ARCH Coefficient  in GARCH Models ? I tried to find what is  ARCH Coefficient means. Some says it's for detecting Spillover effect, Some says Volatility Clustering  or other ppl says conditional volatility so I got confused about it.

Comment: Which coefficient, i.e. which (G)ARCH model ($p=?, q=?$)

Comment: it’s EGARCH (1,1) and GJR-GARCH(1,1).   soesifically Variable Alpha (ARCH Term) .  What can ARCH coefficient tells in Conditional Variance  EGARCH and GJR-GARCH ?

Comment: @develarist, I guess neither $p$ nor $q$ but in an estimated model, a coefficient in front of the squared residual. E.g. $\alpha_1$ in the following: $\sigma^2_t=\omega+\alpha_1\varepsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2$.

Comment: Edit your comments into your question

Comment: @RichardHardy,  Yes . That’s what I mean . Thanks for making it clear.